# Why is there color in measured specular reflection of a ruby and other non-metals?

Tags: color, photorealism, pbr

According to this article: http://learnwebgl.brown37.net/10_surface_properties/surface_properties_color.html#id2

measured specular highlights of some dielectric materials such as ruby or emerald are not white (or grey). This goes against the common belief that only metals have coloured reflections. Why is that?

I could not find the original source of the values of the article. It is however cited/used in multiple places on the web. I have verified that i.e. ruby is indeed non-conductive (see abstract of [Negative Absolute Electrical Conductivity of Optically Excited Ruby: Microscopic Nature of the Phenomenon](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-7341-8_47#:%7E:text=Ruby%2C%20Al2O3,a%20subject%20of%20considerable%20interest.)
.)  Looking at [pictures of rubies](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Corundum-winza-17d.jpg) on the internet, I'm not sure if I can see any colour in the specular highlights. Could it be the redness in measured values is just an artefact caused by the translucency of rubies?

Comment: This is a lovely question, but I'm not sure it's a Blender one.. :)

Comment: Maybe ask on a forum dedicated to physics